# Google PageSpeed images

Tags: pagespeed, mod-pagespeed, google-pagespeed

I have pictures on my website which are displayed at a smaller size than the original size except when users click on them (I m using jquery fancybox plugin).
Then I installed PageSpeed Module for Apache.

I don't understand why PageSpeed resize jpeg images to the size they are displayed first even though I haven't added any filters to do so.
So when I click on a picture, the picture displayed is the picture re-sized by pagespeed and not the the picture with the original size.

Below the filters I added in pagespeed.conf

```
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
ModPagespeedFetchWithGzip on
ModPagespeedEnableFilters collapse_whitespace
ModPagespeedEnableFilters convert_meta_tags
ModPagespeedEnableFilters elide_attributes
ModPagespeedEnableFilters inline_google_font_css
ModPagespeedEnableFilters prioritize_critical_css
ModPagespeedEnableFilters combine_javascript
ModPagespeedEnableFilters combine_css
ModPagespeedEnableFilters extend_cache
ModPagespeedEnableFilters remove_comments

ModPagespeedEnableFilters recompress_jpeg
ModPagespeedImageRecompressionQuality -1
ModPagespeedEnableFilters strip_image_color_profile
ModPagespeedEnableFilters strip_image_meta_data
ModPagespeedEnableFilters jpeg_subsampling
ModPagespeedEnableFilters convert_jpeg_to_webp
ModPagespeedEnableFilters convert_to_webp_lossless
ModPagespeedEnableFilters lazyload_images
```

Is someone has any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what I wanted 
https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/config_filters. 
It is written that :

> `ModPagespeedEnableFilters resize_images` is implied by 
>   `ModPagespeedEnableFilter rewrite_images`

I didn't enable `rewrite_images` but because `recompress_images` is a part of `rewrite_images` and `recompress_jpeg` is a part of `recompress_images` my guess is that when you enable `recompress_jpeg` it enables `resize_images`
So I disable `resize_images` by using  `ModPagespeedDisableFilters resize_images`
And now my problem is solved :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess one of the filters are resizing images, try disable them one by one. Or try adding `pagespeed_no_transform` to your `<img />` tag.

Comment: I want pageSpeed to do a lossless recompression (ModPagespeedImageRecompressionQuality -1 ) and strip meta data etc so I don't want to use pagespeed_no_transform.